# Python structural issue: Giving an 'engine' class to everything

Tags: python, oop, structure

I am having some issues making 'bigger than simple scripts and stuff' applications in Python. I have a class called WinMain, a class called Engine, one called State and another called Element. It's laid out like this:

WinMain is the main class of the program, it has a mainLoop function and various other things.

Engine is an object that contains data like images and rendering code.

State is an object held by Engine that has its update method called each time Engine's step function is called.

Elements are objects held by State that are things like gui buttons and pictures to render.

Since my rendering functions are in Engine, how will I get my Elements (held by state) to render things? I suppose I could give each Element the instance of Engine, but that seems to be kind of hacky, because I'd have to do stuff like this: 
`picture = Element(engine, (0, 0), 'gui_image')` (not good)

I'd rather do `picture = Element((0, 0), 'gui_image')` and still some how let the Element render things using Engine.

This seems to be a major structural problem I have with most projects I start, and I can't seem to find a way around it (other than passing a honkload of variables through the arguments of classes and functions). How might I do this?

Comment: I can't really understand the specifics without seeing some basic structure of these classes, but, couldn't elements somehow have the ability to "post" events up to the event loop? Normally there is one global "application" context or in your case "engine" context, and there would have to be some line of communication from elements back up to that event loop.

Comment: @jdi How might said communication work? The elements do not hold the instance of either state class nor the engine class.

Comment: I am not super experienced with actually designing GUI frameworks (I only use them), but maybe it would have to be a way to get the engine instance as a classmethod:  `Engine.instance()`

Comment: @jdi Then you'd (practically - it may *permit* multiple instances, but in practice other code won't do that and just use `Engine.Instance()`) have a singleton. *Sometimes* this is fine, but it makes many issues much harder. For instance, I'd like to test my GUI elements without worrying about some singleton's state. Also, it may make sense to have more than once engine, and if you go this route you exclude yourself from it forever (or at least until you do massive, everything-breaking changes).

Comment: @delnan: I was basically just drawing on my knowledge of the Qt framework. It uses a single QApplication instance that runs the event loop. Only one can exists in an app.

Comment: @jdi I know, and I'm relatively sure the decision makes sense in that context. But that doesn't mean it's the best option for this case.

Comment: @delnan: Agreed. Merely a suggestion :-) I did include the word "maybe"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Engine is an object that contains data like images and rendering code

This sounds like a God class: they're common in GUI code, and the problem you're having is a common effect of that.

What is the conceptual relationship between different stuff in Engine? Does it need to be tightly coupled, or could the Engine just coordinate between the State, a Renderer and some other stuff?

However that bit breaks down, passing the Engine (or Renderer, or whatever) down through the state machine is the only way to avoid a global (or singleton) with your current architecture.

---

The usual way to break this dependency is to use something like an MVC (Model/View/Controller) pattern. Specifically, it sounds like the Engine is already roughly a Controller, and the State and Elements have the Model part covered. However, the Engine, State and Elements are *also* handling the rendering/presentation part: this introduces the coupling.

If you can find a way to publish the State changes to *some observer* (deliberately leaving that vague, because we don't want the State logic to depend too much on the details of the observer), you can make a Renderer listen to State (model) updates and draw them. Now, the observer can be anything you want, so it's easy to mock, and it's also decoupled from the Engine.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do would be to have your "Engine" as an attribute in each "Element" object (or passed as a value when calling the render method in them) - for that, your "State" object would have to know about the Engine instance, and either pass it to each Element when it is instantiated, or at each render method call - which is what seems to trouble you.

Likewise, for "State" to know "Engine", it has to know about it - either at creation time, or at the call to the action that will trigger the rendeging ("state") .

The dynamic nature of Python does have ways you to mitigate having to write all that explicitly everytime - yes - but yoiu have to be careful not to bury it too much, so that your code is unmaintainable. 
Let's see if I can boil it down to some example here:

```
class WinMain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = Engine()

    def loop_once(self):
        self.engine.step()

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State()

    def step(self):
        self.state.update(self)

    def render(self, obj):
        print (obj)

class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.element = Element()

    def update(self, engine):
        self.element.render(engine)

class Element(object):
    def render(self, engine):
        engine.render(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = WinMain()
    win.loop_once()
```

This code pass the Engine object around only when updating -- it is more interesting than having engine fixed as a state attribute or an Element attribute, because it allows Element instances to belong to different Engines altogether.
It also decouples the "engine" parameter from the Element creation time - the part you complained you didn't want to botter with Engine at all - so it can be less messy.

Either way, you have to have the "Elements" know about their "object" someway - if you don't pass the arguments around explicitly, you have to do it implicitly (i.e. to have the "engine" instance known inside "state" and "elements" somehow). One way would be to write a baseclass or metaclass to perform frame introspection when being instantiated, and bind the "self" variable in the calling context to an attribute in the new object.
This implicit way of doing it smells awful. :-)  Another way is to keep your object's relationships in a separate data structure, with a DOM interface that your methods could navigate. But then, you'd have to make an extra call to annotate the relationship anyway (maybe the extra call could go on a introspecting baseclass or metaclass, like above).

Thinking a little more - the Python Aplication server "zope" solves this problem using "acquisition": all objects in a zope application lie in a tree - when one tries to retrieve an attribute from an object that does not have it (for example, on trying to call an element's "render" method), the acquisition mechanism searchs for that attribute "upwards" on the tree, until it finds a parent that sports the method. It is then called, and gets the original object as a parameter. It is a possible solution for you, but would not only require a base class that implements the acquisition mechanism, but it would not work if you keep your child objects inside standard Python container objects (like lists and dictionaries) - it would only work if the children were direct attributes of an object implementing the acquisistion protocol.

Here goes a naive "Acquisition" implementation for a simplification of your case:

```
class WinMain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.struct = []
        self.engine = Engine()

    def loop_once(self):
        self.engine.step()


class TraverseError(AttributeError):
    pass

class AquisitionBase(object):
    tree = {}      

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # __getattr__ is only invoked when the original object does not have
        # attr by itself
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__.tree[id(self)], attr)
        except (IndexError, AttributeError), error:
            raise TraverseError(error)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, obj):
        cls = self.__class__
        # Anotate parent:
        cls.tree[id(obj)] = self
        return super(AquisitionBase,self).__setattr__(attr, obj)


class Engine(AquisitionBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State()

    def step(self):
        self.state.update()

    def render(self, obj):
        print (obj)

class State(AquisitionBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.element = Element()

    def update(self):
        self.element.render(self.element)

class Element(AquisitionBase):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = WinMain()
    win.loop_once()
```

Note that you can overcome the 
matter about containers, if you have, say, lists or dicts containing your "Elements",
by creating subclasses of list and dict that are aware of this scheme, and basically
implement a `__setitem__` method that anotates the parent of the object being 
attributed there as well.

Essentially - anyway one comes to think about it, passing the "engine" argument around sounds better - even though Python could do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python so excuse me if (when) I get the syntax wrong, but the general OO answer would be to pass the `engine` object to the function of the element that does the rendering.

So in the `Engine`'s step function you'd have something like:

```
state.Update(this)      - so State gets a reference to the engine.
```

You could also give the `State` a reference to `Engine` when it's created if you prefer.

Then in the `state.Update()` method you'd do:

```
element.Render(engine)
```

This is probably inside a loop where you iterate over the collection of elements held by the `state` object.

Comment: If I did this I'd have to pass the engine to every function that needed to render stuff, when I'd rather have the freedom to render from any function in an Element. However, if this is the OO thing to do, I'll take it into consideration.

Comment: If many of the functions in the element need the engine, then pass a reference to the engine into the constructor as you said in your question.

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer not to clutter my __init__ function's arguments with the engine.

Comment: But if the elements need the engine to do their rendering you have to pick one of the two options.  Either pass the engine reference to the element's constructor and store it internally, or pass it in to the methods that need it.

Comment: There is one other way which is the implement `Engine` as a singleton.  I don't know if this is possible in Python.  The problem with the Singleton pattern, though, is that makes testing much more tricky.

Comment: @jsbueno - I thought it would be, but I didn't want to say so without certainty.  I can spell Python, but that's about as far as my knowledge of the language goes ;-)

Comment: @AndrewCooper: The "straightforward" example in my answer is a good place to get a feeling of one of Python's characteristics I like the most: compactness. Take your time to take a look at it :-)